# Using neural networks in an unconventional way to estimate model parameters

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, model-fitting

I just started looking into machine learning and neural networks in order to solve a very specific problem.

I have millions of images illustrating a disk like this:

[image]

The position and radius of the disk in each image can vary. Along with each image I have three associated real numbers. These three numbers represent the three parameters of the disk model used to evaluate the image: `x_position`, `y_position`, and `radius`.

What I want is the following:

- Train a network using the images and the associated parameter values. These should be the only input.
- Use the trained network to estimate the values of the three parameters of any disk image I might supply after the training.

In other words, I want to estimate the parameters of a parametric model in an image without my software knowing anything about the analytical form of the model.

I understand that this approach is an overkill. I could easily use a gradient descent minimizer to solve this problem, but I really want to do it using the above approach. Furthermore, in reality the model I use to generate the images is not a simple disk but a much more complex one which takes way more time to generate. Also, this data (millions of images along with their associated parameter values) are already generated, so there is plenty of data for training.

Unfortunately I can not find a single example on the internet for this particular problem. Most of the examples I find are either classifiers or optimizers of a particular function. My case is different: The neural network should know nothing about the analytical form of the model (disk in the above example) and should be trained using the input data I mention above. Due to my limited knowledge on machine learning (just started reading) and the very unconventional approach to the problem, I don't even know how to Google what I want.

Can someone point me to the right direction?

- Are there any online examples I should look into?
- How do I Google the above approach? (I know, this question sounds silly)
- Examples in Python, C, C++ are preferable

Comment: The key word you are looking for is "Regression", i.e. search for "neural network regression". As you work with images, you will definitely want to look into "convolutional neural networks". Hope this keywords help you get started.

Comment: Also search for IOU (Intersection over Union) loss to optimize segmentation problems